# Retargeting Mixamo MoCap fbx file in Ellie Rig

Tags: rigging, armature

I have a problem. When I click on Retarget Animatoin from Rokoko add-on, the Ellies rig (https://studio.blender.org/characters/ellie/v1/) explode.
Can anyone suggest me what the problem is?
With a rig done in Rigify, with the same process, everything works perfectly.
Thank you for your help.
Mastro3D

[image]

Comment: The Ellie rig is a purpose-built rig and much more complex than the ordinary Rigify one. I think it's very unlikely to work with an external third-party addon.

Comment: Do you think creating an intermediate rig is a solution that can work?

Comment: I've no idea to be honest. The Rokoko addon is not a native Blender addon so is outside the remit of this Q&A site anyway.

Comment: Thank you John. I take advantage of your kindness to ask you the last question: where can I find a good character with complete human rig, made with Rigify and Blender 4, to test MoCap Files, anim layer etc?
In "studio.blender.org/characters/" they are all old rigs and all have the same retargeting problem.

Comment: Again I've no idea I'm afraid. We can't really answer questions about resources here but you might like to look at this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender.